# Listing elements vs dataframe description When happens when?

Tags: python, pandas

This is likely very simple but I can't figure out what's wrong. 
I am having trouble listing elements of a DataFrame. Sometimes the elements of a DataFrame are listed and sometimes it's simply a description of the number and types of the data columns. 
I know that the number of rows is a factor but even when I have only a few rows, I only get the description back. 
For example:
If I have a DataFrame called 'allpledges', it gives me a description

```
In [5]:

allpledges

Out[5]:

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 305384 entries, 0 to 305383
Data columns:
Pledge#       305384  non-null values
Source        305384  non-null values
Date          305384  non-null values
Break         305384  non-null values
Progcode      237002  non-null values
```

Which is understandable because it's too many rows to display. 
But when I try to view a few, it still gives me the same thing

```
In [13]:

allpledges[:5]

Out[13]:

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns:
Pledge#       5  non-null values
Source        5  non-null values
Date          5  non-null values
Break         5  non-null values
Progcode      0  non-null values
```

When what I wanted was the top five rows listed out. I have seen this done in tutorials, but can't figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These settings are controlled in the [`options`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html#working-with-package-options) (I suspect you're looking for `max_rows` or `max_columns`, but there are many options seen in the `set_options` docstring):

```
In [11]: pd.options.display.max_columns
Out[11]: 20
```

And change them using `set_option`:

```
In [12]: pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)
```

*If the DataFrame **either** has more columns or more rows than these settings it will abbreviate.*

For example:

```
In [17]: df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.arange(10).reshape(5,2))

In [18]: pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 4)

In [19]: df
Out[19]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns:
0    5  non-null values
1    5  non-null values
dtypes: int64(2
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I didn't know the setting applied to both rows and columns. I was inadvertently obscuring the problem since I actually have 26 columns but only pasted part of the output to make it more readable.

Comment: @chrisfs I was wondering how it could be true with the DataFrame you gave! (but was convinced it had to be this!) :)